# Using Shiny(R) and Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, web, scope, shiny

Im trying to implement a login (with Discord) button to my website. The [authentication process](https://github.com/DusterTheFirst/Login-With-Discord) was made with JS. Alright, the problem is that I need to access JS global variables from R (with Shiny, to change the UI as I need). I searched a lot but I didn't find anything that can help me :/

Comment: Take a look here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html, go to Scenario 2.

Comment: Does this help: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html? It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly needs to happen?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shiny.onInputChange solved my problem